# Social logins - User flows and application role assignment

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In my previous application setup I was using AzureAD settings (i.e. "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/") and was able to use custom application roles assigned to users logged in via social login accounts (e.g. Microsoft) to control the authorization process in my application. However, after changing the setup to Azure ADB2C (i.e. "Instance": "https://.b2clogin.com") where userflows apply, the same social logins are being denied access to respective resources (i.e. controllers) despite assignment to the roles. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked through [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin)? You may be missing a migration step. Please let me know if you still have the issue.

Best,
James